# Windows Server display settings not showing as it should

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 server, I've set the:

"Region and Language" -> "Formats" -> "Danish (Denmark"

When I see the settings here, and when I click the "Additional Settings", it seems correct. However, in my application, it is not set correct. Here my output is still American.

For instance, these two situations I get the problem:

- Datetime.ToString() gives 11/4/2012 1:18:38 PM instead of 04/11/2012 13:18:38 .
- When I input a double with 50,00 it is ignored and is set to 5000. When using a dot, it works. it should be a decimal

Of course I could all set this in the application specifically, but I wonder why it is set to English as default when I've set the Formats to Danish.

I've also set the following:

- Location = "Denmark"
- Default Input Language = "Danish"

How do I fix it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET runs under a different user account, so you'll need to copy the regional settings across.

In the *Region and Language* control panel, on the *Administrative* tab, you should have a *Copy settings...* button. This will copy the settings from your account to the welcome screen, system accounts and new user accounts.

Another thing to check would be the `<globalization>` section in your `web.config` file - you might be picking up the culture settings from the user's browser.